# What's the best way to set up a Keystore for a spring server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keystore

Still getting familiar with Spring so be patient with me. I have an application containing several services accepting requests via HTTP and I need to change it to HTTPS.

I have two problems to solve:

- Generate a keystore on startup
- Tell Spring where the keystore is

I have a method to create the keystore and I could either write onto a file or save it in some property attribute.

What's the best way for doing so? For the first part I'm not sure at which point of the execution I should do it, whether before or after the application context is getting initialized.

For the second part it seems I can only do so by setting the property server.ssl.keystore or is there a way of setting the property before it get's ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this isn't how you design a production ready application.

TLS termination should be handled by the proxy that sits in front of your API.

But if you still insist to have your tls enabled in your api spring-boot provides a property `server.ssl.key-store` where you can specify where the p12 is

Comment: Is there a way to keep traffic encrypted after TLS termination? We do have a set up with a reverse proxy

Comment: This is outside of the scope of your question. Usually the reverse proxy and api sits behind your firewall and inside a private vpc so having encrypted traffic between these two is little moot. If for whatever reason your architect thinks it's a good idea then `server.ssl.key-store` that points to a p12 created somehow by your deplyment process.